# Automatically upload file to site using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, automation

I am trying to build a chrome extension where users will upload a photo of themselves to the chrome extension, and any time a site has a "upload profile picture" input field, the extension will automatically upload the image.

I fully understand that the automation of file input is a security vulnerability and is fully unsupported by most browsers, but I have heard that it is possible to do so using a Chrome extension (I also know that it is possible using Selenium WebDriver). Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking if it is possible to create?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. I have found that it is not in fact possible.